# PHP Trying to get property 'country' of non-object from ipinfo.io service

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) service to detect the country of users who visit my site and redirect them to the appropriate page.
I am using code like this in index.php page:

```
function getip() {
    if($_SERVER) {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
                return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        else {
            return '0.0.0.0';
        }
    }
    else {
        if( getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ) ) {
            return getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' );
        }
        else if( getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ) ) {
            return getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' );
        }
        else if( getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' ) ) {
            return getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
        }
        else {
            return '0.0.0.0';
        }
    }
}

function getCountry(){
    $ip = getip();
    $url="http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json";
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
    curl_close($curlSession);
    return $jsonData->country;
}

$country=getCountry();
```

Basically, this code works fine and the country is determined correctly, but sometimes the following error appears in the logs:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'country' of non-object in /pub/home/myserver/mysite/index.php on line 65
```

I assume that users also get an error when trying to access my site.
Why does this error sometimes occur and how can I get around it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: When the error does occur, you should debug what `$jsonData` is. That error is saying it's not an Object, so you can't use `->country` (object access). But without knowing what `$jsonData` actually is when that error is thrown, there isn't much we can do to help...

Comment: Ok, I've added code to log data from the $jsonData variable in case this error occurs again.
If I enter the problematic IP directly on the ipinfo.io service website, then no errors occur and the country is determined correctly. It's weird.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. I've used ipinfo in the past too and never had any issues. I wonder if you're getting some kind of communication drop, and not receiving anything from the server? Although I would expect a different error in that case 

Comment: No, the connection with the server is excellent. It seems to me that this error may occur due to the fact that the getip() function cannot always determine the exact IP of the user and returns "'0.0.0.0", so the ipinfo.io service transmits an error that is not an object in the $jsonData array. How can the error be avoided in this case, and is there another way to determine the user's IP that would not return "'0.0.0.0" instead of the real IP?

Comment: Ah ha, yeah that makes sense! From my experience, those are the variables I would check to determine IP for request; I'm not sure why you'd be hitting your fallback case of `else { return '0.0.0.0' ; }`. Or, is it one of that `$_SERVER` or `getenv()` calls that is returning `0.0.0.0`? Might need some debugging breakpoints; echo out all the different variables. Also, point for coding style, you can do `if (...) { return ...; }`, then another `if (...) { return ...; }`, then finally just `return '0.0.0.0';`; the `else`/`else if` statements are not needed 

Comment: @Tim, To be honest, I don't know why the `getip()` function should return `'0.0.0.0'` in cases where none of the previous conditions are met, and why they might not be. I just copied this function from another code where it was necessary to find out the IP of the site visitor. Perhaps there are other ways, but it seemed to me that this method is the most accurate.

Comment: @Tim But anyway, thanks for your advice. I'll change the code to remove the extra `else if {...;}`. But I don't think this will solve the problem of not getting the user's IP, so for now I'll just add an `if ($ip!=='0.0.0.0'){...;}` condition to the `getCountry()` function . At the very least, this will eliminate the occurrence of an error when accessing the ipinfo.io service

Comment: Yup! That sounds like a good plan to prevent triggering that error in the meantime. Hope you get this sorted out!, and cheers!